# PHP returning error 402 on requests

Tags: php, curl

Suddenly all requests made by PHP to external servers (cURL, file_get_contents(urL)) are returning a strange 402 HTTP Error. At first I thought it was a problem at Flickr API, but testing different URLs (AFAIK only on HTTPs) I keep receiving this error.

The problem is that I on my localhost the PHP have the same configuration (or at least should be), same script, and it works fine.

Logs doesn't show anything. Any ideas where might the problem be?
Thanks

Comment: what are you doing to get a "Payment Required" error?

Comment: "or at least should be" confirming this beyond any doubt should be your first step. Also, try non-https urls to rule out any issue there.

Comment: @Fallenreaper I really don't know!!! Nothing, I guess, since it is working on localhost.

Comment: @PatrickQ, I tested several URL, it looks like that the problem is with Flickr API URL. The strange thing is that if I call the URL with wget with same parameters, the API gives me the correct result. PHP have the same configuration!

Comment: We started experiencing this issue on some (but not all) of our servers with PHP's file_get_contents() at 08:26 UTC on Wednesday.  We are supplying an API key, and using that same API key with cURL via the terminal is working fine - so this is really odd behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've contacted Flickr team, and you can check the result here: https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/yws-flickr/conversations/topics/8912

> Sorry for the inconvenience.  If you are impacted by the 402's, please email me your API keys and we can unblock you.  We were getting repeated attacks (primarily from EC2) and had to block out some suspicious traffic over the weekend.  We may have been too aggressive and blocked API users that we should not have.

They had some problem with attacks from AWS EC2, just contacted them to resolve this issue.